# alfresco search category case sensitive

Tags: search, alfresco, case-sensitive

I'm very new on Alfresco.

In a web script  i  have implemented category search.

```
var result  = search.query("TYPE:\"cm:category\"  AND @cm\\:name:CAt*").
```

but unfortnatly this search on category seems to be case sensitive. the results of `search.query("TYPE:\"cm:category\"  AND @cm\\:name:CAt*")` and `search.query("TYPE:\"cm:category\"  AND @cm\\:name:cat*")` are different.

How can i make  search case insensitive?

Comment: can you please add code of webscript.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you should have done something with your lucene or solr configuration.As it seems work perfectly in my instance.Below is working image in my instance.

[image]

Or may be you are doing something wrong while testing.As you are executing this in your code may be some problem might be there.

Check your result in node browser.

Comment: Thank you Krutik. I have checked result in node browser.  I'm very confused now. 
In node browser  search is case insensitive . 

In fact  `TYPE:"cm:category"  AND @cm\:name:"dou*"` and   `TYPE:"cm:category"  AND @cm\:name:"DOU*"` return the same result. 

I don't understand why  in my webscript it isn't the same results.

Comment: Hi Krutik, bellow my webscript code `

var term = args["term"];
var typeData = args["typeData"];
var searchResult ;
if( "1" == typeData )
{
 searchResult = search.query({query: "TYPE:\"sc:site\"" });
}
else if( "2" == typeData )
{
 searchResult = search.query({query: "TYPE:\"sc:fonction\"" }); 
}
else  
{
 var query  =  "TYPE:\"cm:category\"  AND (@cm\\:name:\""+term +"*\" OR  @cm\\:synonymes:\"" + term + "*\" OR @cm\\:synonymes:\"*;" + term +"*\" OR @cm\\:synonymes:\"*;\ " + term +"*\" )"   ;
 searchResult = search.query({query: query });
}

model.searchResult  = searchResult`

Answer (score 0):

bellow my webscript (well formatted version)

```
listData.get.js : 

var term = args["term"];
var typeData = args["typeData"];
var searchResult ;
if( "1" == typeData )
{
    searchResult = search.query({query: "TYPE:\"sc:site\"" });
}
else if( "2" == typeData )
{
    searchResult = search.query({query: "TYPE:\"sc:fonction\"" }); 
}
else  
{
    var query  =  "TYPE:\"cm:category\"  AND @cm\\:name:\""+term +"*\""   ;
    searchResult = search.query({query: query });
}
```

And here is the descriptor file

```
listData.get.desc.xml :

    <webscript>
      <shortname>Une description du webscript</shortname>
      <description> </description>
      <url>/listData</url>
      <authentication>user</authentication>
    </webscript>
```

So i call webscript with `http://localhost:9090/share/proxy/alfresco/listData?term=D`

Comment: I think it's because of locale (language) used by my webscript. 
But i'm not sur because i don't know how  to check  locale in webscript.

Comment: what is the URL which you are firing.

Comment: Hi krutik.

I have updated my last post to include my  webscript descriptor code. To answer to your question , the webscript is called by `http://localhost:9090/share/proxy/alfresco/listData?term=D`

Comment: Hi krutik.Please do you  see some thing wrong i'm doing? How  to know  current locale in alfresco webscript ? and how to force it to certain value ?